# Cycle a array on click javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem,when cycle my array with cycle for;show only final element.Why?

MY JS:

```
var dom = new Array();


/*-----------------RIDDLES--------------*/
dom[0] = "How many cats..";
dom[1] = "How many dogs..";
dom[2] = "How many birds..";

function guess()
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < dom.length ; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("riddle").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = dom[i];
    }

}
```

MY HTML:

```
  <div id="riddle">
        <p>  </p>
    </div>


    <button  onclick="guess()">Next</button>
```

Why don't cycle all elements of arrays?

Comment: Do you want each element of the array to appear in turn, or all of them to appear at once?

Comment: i want each element of the array to appear in turn

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this for example:

```
var dom = new Array();

/*-----------------RIDDLES--------------*/
dom[0] = "How many cats..";
dom[1] = "How many dogs..";
dom[2] = "How many birds..";

// Initial pointer
var i = 0;

var p = document.getElementById("riddle").getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function guess() {
    if (i < dom.length) {
        p.innerText = dom[i];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else {
        alert('All solved!')
    }
}

// Display tyhe first one
guess();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7wucF/1/

Comment: @user3467605 Because on every click when `guess` executed, you were looping over the whole array of riddles setting the innerText of the paragraph. So the the each item was simply overwriting the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="riddle">
    <p>  </p>
</div>


<button id="nxt">Next</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var dom = ["How many cats..","How many dogs..","How many birds.."];
var index = -1;
document.getElementById("nxt").onclick= function() {
    // Prevent getting past length of array
    if((index + 1) >= dom.length) { return; }
    index++;
    document.getElementById("riddle").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = dom[index];
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/m79uY/1/).

Comment: In this mode i show all elements,I would like to cycle the array element on click

Comment: @user3467605 View edit. In the new edit you don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: @user3467605 Apologies, there was an error and I had edited the post to make the code work. Set this as answer if it works :-)

Comment: This will get an array overflow if you click again when it's on birds. If the index is 2, you need to set it to 0 instead of 3.

Comment: @Nate Kerkhofs Yes thanks for reminding me, edited the code already.

Answer (score 1):

Better to not access DOM method inside loop, it will be written to the every time the loop iterates. And DOM manipulation is expensive in js.

> var dom = [];
>
> ```
> /*-----------------RIDDLES--------------*/ 
> dom[0] = "How many cats.."; 
> dom[1] = "How many dogs.."; 
> dom[2] = "How many birds..";
>
> function guess() {
>     var arr = []; 
>
>     for (var i = 0 ; i < dom.length ; i++)
>     {
>        arr.push(dom[i]);
>     }
>
>     document.getElementById("riddle").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText
> ```
>
> = arr.join('');
>       }

Answer (score 0):

I have tested you'r code and seems that is the onclick event which is not working good, just try to do it with `addEventListener`, like in that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cgz7W/2/)

Code:

```
var dom = new Array();
var i = 0;
/*-----------------RIDDLES--------------*/
dom[0] = "How many cats..";
dom[1] = "How many dogs..";
dom[2] = "How many birds..";

document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("riddle").getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    e.innerHTML = dom[i];
    if(i>1)
        i=0
    else
        i++;
},false);
```

html:

```
<div id="riddle">
    <p></p>
</div>
<button  id="b1">Next</button>
```